# How can I sell my Bitcoin Gold? Do any exchanges support BTG deposits?

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins, bitcoin-gold, altcoin-trade

Given I have Bitcoin Gold in my own wallet, what practical ways are there to trade this, either to other crypto-currencies or to fiat? Is there a list of exchanges that support Bitcoin Gold deposits?

Answer (score -1):

bittrex, you can trade for BTC and USDT